# echo several rows and column of mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to echo all rows and column from a mysql query search, here my current php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
     mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect mysql server');
       mysql_select_db('DBChemAlive')  or die('cannot connect database');

$Inputdata=(isset($_GET["data"])) ? $_GET["data"] : NULL;
$data=mysql_real_escape_string(filter_var($Inputdata, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));

    $q=mysql_query("select CompType, Method, Base from GeoAndEnergies where SMILES='".$data."' ") or die(mysql_error());
 $n=mysql_num_rows($q); //not mysql_fetch_row, as that does not return count but an array
 if($n>0)
 {
//   $info=mysql_fetch_row($q);
$val='';
   while($info=mysql_fetch_row($q))
    {
      if($val!='')
          $val.=' < ';
      $val.= $info[0];
    }
    echo $val;
  }

?>
```

It is echoing row1col1 < row2col1 < .... rowncol1, what I would like is to get row1col1 < row1col2 < .... < row2col1 < row2col2... all rows and all columns

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to just print the first row? Can you clarify what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will likely have to adapt it a little(formatting)

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_row($q))
{
    if($val != '' ){
        $val.=' < ';
    }
    foreach($info as $key => $value){
        $val .= $value . ' < ';
    }   
}
```